# How to determine the most-used color among 16 different pixels?

Tags: c#, colors, compare, equals

I have the following code:

```
for (int iy = y; iy < y + 4; iy++)
    for (int ix = x; ix < x + 4; ix++)
     {
         Color c = default_image.GetPixel(ix,iy);
     }
 }
```

Now I need to determine which color from these 16 colors is the most used one. How can I do this?

Comment: Keep it simple by the way, i'm new at this

Comment: We wouldn't have guessed it. Start by learning about loops, then about collections . A Dictionay<Color, int> would help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution:

First it collects the colors with their counts in a Dictionary collection.

For this it uses a double loop over the dimensions of the Bitmap

Then is orders them descending into a second collection.

Finally it shows the fist i.e. largest count in a `MessageBox`:

```
  Dictionary<Color, int> colors = new Dictionary<Color, int>();

  for (int iy = y; iy < y + 4; iy++)
    for (int ix = x; ix < x + 4; ix++)
     {
        Color c = default_image.GetPixel(ix,iy);
        if (colors.ContainsKey(c)) colors[c]++; else colors.Add(c, 1);
     }
    var vvv = colors.OrderByDescending(el => el.Value);
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Color {0} found {1} times.", 
                    vvv.First().Key, vvv.First().Value),  "Result");
```

Comment: thanks but it only has to check 16 pixels can we also fix that

Comment: If they are always in the top left corner, simply let the loops go while: `y < 4` and `x < 4` ..

Comment: no, the x and y were readed in before as the position from where it has to read

Comment: OK, have a look. These are things though you need to do for yourself..!

Answer (score 1):

First put the `Colors` into a collection,such as array.Then you can use LINQ `GroupBy` to group them, sort the groups in *descending* order based on count then get the first group which has the most colors in it:

```
Color[] colors = new [] { color1, color2, color3, ... };
var mostUsedColor = colors.GroupBy(c => c)
                          .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                          .First().Key;
```

Comment: the first x from GroupBy(x => x) is underlined in red how to fix

Comment: Probably because you already using an 'x' . replace it by `el => el.Count` or just about anything. It is just a temporary name..

Comment: @JonasAnon also make sure you have `using System.Linq;`at the top of your file